# What's proper method for broadcast in Go grpc?

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a tcp server and multiple tcp clients.
The tcp server is use grpc stream to send to all tcp client.
My current solution is:
On the grpc client code, just connect to the grpc stream.
On the grpc stream server code::

```
func (s *rpcServer) DataStream(req *pb.SearchRequest, stream pb.SearchService_DataStreamServer) error {
  for {
    if data, ok := myMapData[req.ID]; ok {
      stream.Send(data)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
  }
}
```

This method is based on period time update.  Is there better method if I create new data for some subscriber, then just send them?

Comment: There is no broadcast or pub/sub in grpc. You have to keep a list of all connected clients. Each client connection will create a separate stream on the server. If you have data for one of the subscribers, you have to keep a map of all active subscribers, and write the data to the stream for the subscriber.

Comment: @bserdar Do you any exist similar code for demo this concept?

Comment: just search for the **observer pattern**, there's a lot of code and articles out there describing it. It pretty much covers what @bserdar described.